# Select Menu isn't getting value from it's sub Menu Item

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, menuitem

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to create a category list with **Material UI**

- Parent Menu Item
- Child Menu Item by Parent Menu Category

#### What I'm getting

- I'm getting only parent menu value.
- Whenever I click on child item, than it showing it's parent Menu.

#### Code

Here I've create a codesanbox, Please help to get out from this.

- [Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-menu-1qdvu2)
- Please check console for see event.

```js
<Select
          displayEmpty
          defaultValue=""
          value={search}
          onChange={handleChange}
          id="grouped-select"
          input={<OutlinedInput />}
          label="Category"
          size="small"
          sx={{
            width: "160px",
            height: "100%",
            borderRadius: 0,
            textTransform: "uppercase"
          }}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            if (selected.length === 0) {
              return (
                <Typography variant="subtitle2">Select Category</Typography>
              );
            }
            return <Typography variant="subtitle2">{selected}</Typography>;
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="select category">
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">Select Category</Typography>
          </MenuItem>

          {categories.map((category) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={category}
              sx={{
                lineHeight: "20px",
                display: "block",
                backgroundColor: "none"
              }}
              value={category}
            >
              <Typography variant="subtitle2">{category}</Typography>

              {category === "Baby Products" &&
                babyProducts.map((item) => (
                  <List key={item} sx={{ padding: 0 }}>
                    <MenuItem
                      sx={{
                        lineHeight: "12px",
                        display: "block"
                      }}
                      value={item}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                      <Typography variant="subtitle2">{item}</Typography>
                    </MenuItem>
                  </List>
                ))}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
```

```js
const babyProducts = [
  "Baby",
  "Baby Cereal",
  "Baby Honey",
  "Biscotti",
  "Formula",
  "Milk",
  "Juice",
  "Puree",
  "Bath & Skincare",
  "Diapers & Wipes",
  "Huggies",
  "Kidz",
  "MamyPoko",
  "Molfix",
  "Pampers & Wipes",
  "Oral Care",
];

const chocolates = [
  "Assorted",
  "Cadbury",
  "Candy",
  "Chocolate Balls",
  "Chocolate Bars",
  "Kit-Kat",
  "Lolipops",
  "Marshmallow",
  "Mints&Gums",
  "Toblenore",
];
```

Comment: Please post the code as a minimal reproducible example  in the question itself, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to nested `MenuItems`. You can use nested arrays instead with the `marginLeft` on a subcategory:

```
{categories.map((cat) => [
  renderCategory(cat),
  renderCategoryItems(cat)
])}
```

```
const renderCategory = (category) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      key={category}
      sx={{
        lineHeight: "20px",
        display: "block",
        backgroundColor: "none"
      }}
      value={category}
    >
      <Typography variant="subtitle2">{category}</Typography>
    </MenuItem>
  );
};
```

```
const renderCategoryItems = (category) => {
  const list = category === "Baby Products" ? babyProducts : [];
  return list.map((item) => (
    <MenuItem
      key={item}
      sx={{
        lineHeight: "12px",
        display: "block"
      }}
      value={item}
    >
      <Typography
        sx={{
          marginLeft: "16px"
        }}
        variant="subtitle2"
      >
        {item}
      </Typography>
    </MenuItem>
  ));
};
```

**Update**

If more subcategories are required, you can describe them as follows:

```
const subCategories = {
  "Baby Products": [
    ...
  ],
  "Chocolate": [
    ...
  ]
};
```

And update `renderCategoryItems` function:

```
const list = subCategories[category] || [];
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-menu-forked-m5e7uv?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks, How to update it if I had another sub category data of `chocolate` parent category ? I've added those 2 category in my question.

Comment: @mrhrifat I have updated the answer and example.